# Bridging networks problems

Tags: networking, router, wifi

In my setup I have 3 computers and 2 (wireless d-link) routers.

Computer1 has ethernet and wireless interfaces

> ethernet : 192.168.0.x (DHCP)
>   wireless : 192.168.10.254 (static)

Computer 2 has ethernet with two ips

> ethernet1 : 192.168.0.90 (static)
>   ethernet2 : 192.168.10.110 (static)

Computer 3 is a particular device with a hardcoded ip that I can't change

> wireless : 192.168.10.41 (static)

Router1 manages internet and DHCP for network 192.168.0.0/24

Router2 is more complicated. I don't use DHCP. I use it to bridge between both networks. Its static ip is 192.168.10.1

Computer1 can ping Computer2.
Computer1 can ping Computer3.
Computer1 can ping Router1.
Computer1 cannot ping Router2.

Computer2 cannot ping Computer3.
Computer2 can ping Router2.

Router1 can ping Router1
Router2 can ping Computer2
**Router2 cannot ping Computer1**
**Router2 cannot ping Computer3**

This is very weird. Router2 manages the wireless connection, it should be able to ping its own computers right?

My question is obviously : How can I make it so Computer2 can access everything else.

This is a traditional case of "it was working before christmas and now it doesn't".

The ethernet wiring is as follow :

[ Computer1 ]----[ Router1 ]---[ Router2 ]---[ Computer3 ]

I am using switch (lan) ports on Router1/2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Silly me there was another router hidden somewhere broadcasting the same SSID

Answer (score 1):

What vendor / software are you using for routing?

Does router2 know about the 192.168.0.0/24 subnet? 
If it doesn't, it will try and respond via it's default gateway.

Router1 should know that 192.168.10.0/24 is reachable by 192.168.10.X (Where X is your router2's IP)
Router2 should know that 192.168.0.0/24 is reachable by 192.168.0.Y (Where Y is your router1's IP)

The easiest method to do this is to simply add static routes to each router's routing table.

This is different on different vendors of router, especially small home or office (SOHO) routers.

Also, does Computer3 have a default route set?

Comment: I use D-Link 628 routers. I'm really not sure about Computer3. It is just a small box with antenas and an on/off switch. I don't have console access to it

Comment: I'm still a little confused as to the layout of your network, how does router2 connect to router1? Is there a cable from router1's LAN port to router2's WAN port or it's LAN port? Does each router have it's own internet connection?

Comment: Everything is wired in the LAN ports. Router1 has a WAN connection for internet but this works correctly